# lxml in virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, lxml

These seems like a common issue but I cannot find a solution (looks like others have the issue on Windows so they build from a binary file).

Anyway, I want to add "python-docx" to my virtual environment. but I get an issues installing lxml

```
(SM_PCa) rands-mbp-2:SM_PCa randwvb$ pip install python-docx
Collecting python-docx
  Using cached python_docx-0.8.11-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting lxml>=2.3.2 (from python-docx)
  Using cached lxml-4.9.2.tar.gz (3.7 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: lxml
  Building wheel for lxml (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [218 lines of output]
      Building lxml version 4.9.2.
      Building without Cython.
      Building against libxml2 2.9.4 and libxslt 1.1.29
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/includes
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/html
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/isoschematron
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/isoschematron
      copying src/lxml/etree.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/etree_api.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/objectify.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/etree.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/public-api.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/xmlid.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/cleanup.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/xslt.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/xpath.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/debug.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/serializer.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/classlookup.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/saxparser.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/objectpath.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/relaxng.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/xinclude.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/iterparse.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/parser.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/dtd.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/xmlerror.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/readonlytree.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/extensions.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/xmlschema.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/schematron.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/docloader.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/nsclasses.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/parsertarget.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/xsltext.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/proxy.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml
      copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/includes
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/isoschematron/resources
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      running build_ext
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/src
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/src/lxml
      clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -Isrc -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/Users/randwvb/.virtualenvs/SM_PCa/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11 -c src/lxml/etree.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.11/src/lxml/etree.o -w -flat_namespace
      In file included from src/lxml/etree.c:96:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11/Python.h:23:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:62:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:807:2: error: Unsupported architecture
      #error Unsupported architecture
       ^
      In file included from src/lxml/etree.c:96:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11/Python.h:23:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:64:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: architecture not supported
      #error architecture not supported
       ^
      In file included from src/lxml/etree.c:96:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11/Python.h:23:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:64:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
      typedef __int64_t       __darwin_blkcnt_t;      /* total blocks */
              ^
      note: '__int128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
      typedef __int32_t       __darwin_blksize_t;     /* preferred block size */
              ^
      note: '__int128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
      typedef __int32_t       __darwin_dev_t;         /* dev_t */
              ^
      note: '__int128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_gid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:61:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_id_t;          /* [XSI] pid_t, uid_t, or gid_t*/
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:62:9: error: unknown type name '__uint64_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint64_t      __darwin_ino64_t;       /* [???] Used for 64 bit inodes */
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:68:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'
      typedef __darwin_natural_t __darwin_mach_port_name_t; /* Used by mach */
              ^
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:70:9: error: unknown type name '__uint16_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint16_t      __darwin_mode_t;        /* [???] Some file attributes */
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:71:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
      typedef __int64_t       __darwin_off_t;         /* [???] Used for file sizes */
              ^
      note: '__int128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:72:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
      typedef __int32_t       __darwin_pid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
              ^
      note: '__int128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:73:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_sigset_t;      /* [???] signal set */
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:74:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
      typedef __int32_t       __darwin_suseconds_t;   /* [???] microseconds */
              ^
      note: '__int128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:75:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_uid_t;         /* [???] user IDs */
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_useconds_t;    /* [???] microseconds */
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      In file included from src/lxml/etree.c:96:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11/Python.h:23:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:64:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:43:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_wctype_t;
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      In file included from src/lxml/etree.c:96:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11/Python.h:23:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:66:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/wait.h:109:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/signal.h:82:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/signal.h:34:2: error: architecture not supported
      #error architecture not supported
       ^
      In file included from src/lxml/etree.c:96:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11/Python.h:23:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:66:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/wait.h:109:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/signal.h:146:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/_mcontext.h:31:2: error: architecture not supported
      #error architecture not supported
       ^
      fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
      20 errors generated.
      Compile failed: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      creating var
      creating var/folders
      creating var/folders/rv
      creating var/folders/rv/d2kdsbx15_s26_7wktwdl7700000gn
      creating var/folders/rv/d2kdsbx15_s26_7wktwdl7700000gn/T
      cc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /var/folders/rv/d2kdsbx15_s26_7wktwdl7700000gn/T/xmlXPathInitbdl24kin.c -o var/folders/rv/d2kdsbx15_s26_7wktwdl7700000gn/T/xmlXPathInitbdl24kin.o
      /var/folders/rv/d2kdsbx15_s26_7wktwdl7700000gn/T/xmlXPathInitbdl24kin.c:1:10: fatal error: 'libxml/xpath.h' file not found
      #include "libxml/xpath.h"
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      *********************************************************************************
      Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
      Perhaps try: xcode-select --install
      *********************************************************************************
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lxml
  Running setup.py clean for lxml
Failed to build lxml
ERROR: Could not build wheels for lxml, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I was using python11 but someone suggested python10 (stil didn't work).

The virtualenv has nothing else installed.

I've tried `pip install libxml2` and `xcode-select --install` shows they are already installed.

https://github.com/fbchat-dev/fbchat/issues/230 mentioned:

"""
I had this problem when using pip install on a mac. The solution was to create a unicode subdirectory in /opt/local/include/unicode and copy needed header files to it

In other words:
cd /opt/local/include/unicode
sudo mkdir unicode

Then move there and copy needed files
cd unicode
sudo cp ../localpointer.h ../ucnv_err.h ../uenum.h .

the header ucnv_err.h needed these to be in the subdirectory
"""

But I'll be honest, not only do I not know where /opt/local is (my computer tells me they don't exist) but I also don't know where those files to copy are.

Comment: You need to install those libraries on your Linux (or Mac OS) machine.

Comment: libxml is already installed on my machine (it ships with xcode, which is installed). lxml is also already installed. It's something about it being in a virtual environment... 

```
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (4.5.0)
```

Comment: libxml2 is not the same as libxml. I'm pretty sure that the problem is on Mac OS side. This is what the error message is saying.

Comment: sorry, that's what I meant. The package comes from XCode, which is intalled. Trying to install it again gives 

pip install libxml2
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -arkupsafe (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libxml2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for libxml2


it works on my MacOs, just not in the virtual environment.

Comment: Do you know where libxml2 is on Mac Os?

Comment: Your Mac OS thinks that it is in /usr/include/libxml2, and it fails because it can not find it there. So if you know where the libxml2 library is, just compy it to /usr/include/

Comment: thanks. So I found it in /usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.10.2_1 . My Mac doesn't have usr/include and it won't let me create the directory. Do you know how to change it so it looks in usr/local instead of usr/include? And why do you think this is ONLY in the virtual environment?

Comment: I hit this problem with `lxml` 4.9. So I rolled back to 4.8, and the problem disappeared.